# What is the equivalent of runCommand in mongoose?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

In MongoDB shell you can use [`db.runCommand(...)`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.runCommand/). For example to show mongoDB users :

```
> db.runCommand({usersInfo:1})
....
list of users
....
```

This would be useful for [User management commands](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/#user-management-commands)

What is the equivalent in [mongoose](/questions/tagged/mongoose) ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've found out [here](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/4497) that we can use `db.db.command` :

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/test', {useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true});

var db = mongoose.connection;

db.once('open', function callback () {
    db.db.command({usersInfo: 1}, function (err,result){
        console.log(result);
        mongoose.disconnect();
    });
});
```