# How to execute user management commands in Mongoose (db.createUser, db.dropUser)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I need to manage mongoDB users using Mongoose. More specifically, I need to provision database users using a nodeJS script and thus need to create mongoDB users.

In MongoDB shell, I was using the following :

```
> db.createUser(
...     {
...         user: "productUser",
...         pwd: "password123",
...         roles: [
...             {"db":"admin", "role":"dbAdminAnyDatabase" }, 
...             {"db":"admin", "role":"readWriteAnyDatabase"}, 
...             {"db":"admin", "role":"clusterAdmin"}
...         ]
...     }
... )
```

What is the equivalent in Mongoose ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In MongoDB shell `db.getCreateUser` and `db.DropUser` use, under the hood, mongoDB commands that are run via `db.runCommand({createUser: "user1", ....})` and `db.runCommand({dropUser: "user1"})`.

From [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60795102/2614364) we can use mongoDB commands to execute all types of [user management commands](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/nav-user-management/) (creating, deleting, updating, granting roles ...)

The following code add a user, show the user created and the drop this user afterwards:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/admin', {useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true});

var db = mongoose.connection;

db.once('open', async function callback () {
    //show users
    var users = await db.db.command({usersInfo: 1});
    console.log("users", users);

    //create user
    var userCreate = await db.db.command({
        createUser: "productUser",
        pwd: "1234567",
        roles: [
            {"db":"admin", "role":"dbAdminAnyDatabase" }, 
            {"db":"admin", "role":"readWriteAnyDatabase"}, 
            {"db":"admin", "role":"clusterAdmin"}
        ]
    });
    console.log(userCreate.ok === 1 ? "user created" : "user creation failed");

    users = await db.db.command({usersInfo: 1});
    console.log("users",users);

    //drop user
    var userDrop = await db.db.command({
        dropUser: "productUser"
    });
    console.log(userDrop.ok === 1 ? "user removed" : "user drop failed");

    users = await db.db.command({usersInfo: 1});
    console.log("users",users);
});
```

Comment: Looks like you connected to DB "test", however typically users are defined in DB "admin"

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit thanks, yes I was testing locally in a different db but in my AWS DocumentDB cluster it's the regular admin database